# data load using sql loader giving bad records but Batch job succeeding

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-loader

data load using sql loader giving bad records but oracle job succeeding. I want to fail the job if it creates even a single record rejects and creates bad file.
Please help me with this.

Comment: What "oracle job" are we talking about?  Do you have a `dba_jobs` job?  A `dbms_scheduler` job?  A cron job running at the operating system level?  Something else?  Perhaps you just want to specify `errors=0` in your command line.

Comment: We have 3rd party job scheduler which calls a batch script, inside batch script we use SQL loader job to run.

Answer (score 0):

SQL*Loader, by default, allows 50 errors before it will cause the loader job to fail:

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14215/ldr_params.htm

```
errors -- number of errors to allow            (Default 50)
```

Within your control file or on the command line when you call SQL*Loader, if you change the `errors` parameter, you can alter this to whatever you want -- in your case, it sounds like you want zero.

Here is an example:

```
  $SQLDIR/sqlldr /@server.whatevz.com \
    control=/apps/loader/table1.ctl \
    log=/apps/loader/table1.log \
    bad=/apps/loader/table1.err \
    rows=200000 \
    errors=0
```